# Norwegian keyboard layout: AltGr

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an issue wherein a customer in Norway using their keyboard layout is unable to enter the ”@“ character in textboxes and text areas. The application is treating <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as <kbd>Alt</kbd>. What is the actual keycode for <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in the Norwegian keyboard layout? Is there any setting that must be changed to prevent this issue? The customer is using Windows XP, Service pack 3.

Comment: `onkeypress` returns 64 for ALTGR+2 (="@").

Comment: I'm sorry, just read badly. ALTGR returns 17. (So are both CTRLs)

Comment: How did u find this ...using a norwegian keyboard ?

Comment: Actually finnish, but it should be pretty much the same as norwegian. You could ask your customer for this, just to be sure?

Comment: @Temmu - thanks for ur inputs ...i fixed this problem.Issue simulation of Norwegian key board can be done in US key board layout by changing the regional language settings of the os.The Altgr key fires two events ctrl and alt .i just handled both the events and was able to input special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to simulate the issue by changing the layout of the keyboard used, from the control panel. Was able to find out the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key fires two events: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and handled both the events in the Javascript code.